# Custom page template on Wordpress 6.0 not shown when i edit a page

Tags: wordpress

i've created a php file in my theme folder named page-test.

[image: screenshot code]

When i try to bind this template to any page, i can't see it

[image: page attribute]

Impossible to guess what is the problem. Someone could help me ?

Thx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok i got it.

It's not in "page attribute" anymore but in the "modele (in french)" part.

Answer (score -1):

Can you make sure your child theme is activated, i mean where you put your file, also can you change file name to page_test.php

Let me know if problem fixed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for ur help. 
Yes he is activated.
Changing for page_test.php doesn't change anything :(

Comment: Can you please confirm, Drop down not showing or template not showing?

Comment: Dropdown not showing @mukta

Comment: If you have disabled or removed the style.css from the template directory then also it will not work.

So there must be the style.css on template directory then the templates directory will be shown. When you try to remove the style.css from the template directory or using style.css from css folder, then you must be put one style.css on template directory.

Comment: Hey, i've got a style.css in my template directory as u can see on screen.
So i guess it's not the probl i'm facing :x